# split value and search in linq to sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I saved date value in my database like

```
id   dob
1    20/5/1988
2    3/6/1999
3    4/7/1890
```

This is my query

```
 object _x = db.DB_MyDatabase.my_tables
   .Where(x => x.dob.Split('/')[2].Trim() == "1988")
   .ToList();
```

I want to get the first row with `year=1988` . 
But I got this error

```
Unrecognized expression node: ArrayIndex
```

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 2):

Use AsEnumerable() before your Where clause to force the split on client side. The current work you're trying to do has no correspondence on the sql server side and can't be translated properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `AsEnumerable()` before `Where(...)`:

```
object _x = db.DB_MyDatabase.my_tables
              .AsEnumerable()
              .Where(x => x.dob.Split('/')[2].Trim() == "1988")
              .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Substring` as  the below:

```
object _x = db.DB_MyDatabase.my_tables
       .Where(x => x.dob.Trim().Substring(x.dob.Length - 4, 4) == "1988")
       .ToList();
```

Query looks like in sql:

```
WHERE 
    SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(dob)), ((CONVERT(Int,LEN(dob))) - 4) + 1, 4) = '1988'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
object _x = db.DB_MyDatabase.my_tables.Where(x => x.dob.Contains("1988")).ToList();
```

Comment: yes , it will work , but how about date and month ? `Year` has 4 digits but date and month may be same ( 2 digits ) like `12/12/1990` .

Comment: You can use AsEnumerable. But I aware you to do so, cause AsEnumerable() means you load all the table from database into in-memory collection and do manipulations with  in memory collection.

Comment: You can use StartWith("12") to search date and also use Contains("/12/") to search month.